# Problem with dates using CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter library to generate an Excel file in C#.  If I treat all data as strings everything works fine, but I need some cells to be recognized by Excel as date fields.  When I try to set the data type accordingly, the resulting Excel file fails to open in Excel 2003 (or  Excel 2007 for that matter).

In Excel 2003, I get the following error on load:

> Problems came up in the following area
>   during load: Table

I am using the following code to generate the DateTime cells that are causing the problem:

```
string val = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");     
row.Cells.Add(new WorksheetCell(val, DataType.DateTime));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually figured this out.  Thanks to Lance Roberts for nudging me in the right direction.

First, define a WorksheetStyle called dateStyle and set its NumberFormat property to a valid Excel date format:

```
Workbook book = new Workbook();
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add("myWorksheet");

WorksheetStyle dateStyle = book.Styles.Add("dateStyle");
dateStyle.NumberFormat = "Dd Mmm Yy";

WorksheetRow row = book.Worksheets[0].Table.Rows.Add();
```

Then, export the date using the .NET "s" date format and add the cell:

```
string val = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
row.Cells.Add(val, DataType.DateTime, "dateStyle");
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used his library, but work in Excel a lot.  I don't know what he's doing with a datatype for a cell, since they don't work that way.  Dates in Excel cells are all integers with Date Formatting.

I would try to put the date in as an integer, the trick is converting your string to the correct integer.  See [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) for information on Excel's Date as Numbers methodology.  I would then set the WorksheetStyle.NumberFormat Property.

Comment: This is interesting and useful information, but it doesn't provide a solution to my specific problem.

Comment: I was hoping it'd give you a lead to the right answer.  I know a lot of times, a lead has helped me solve a problem.